# click event fire multiple time if i initialize marker multiple time in google maps

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

i first click on map then a marker is shown then i click on marker address is alert first fite,then again i click anywhere on map then i click on marker then this time two times alert is shown,if i click map on third time then 3 times alert shown on markers click,and so on,
why alert on marker click is happeninig multiple times?
why click event fired multiple times?
please help me?

```
     <!DOCTYPE html>
   <html>
       <head>
         <title>Accessing arguments in UI events</title>
         <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
       <meta charset="utf-8">
        <link      href="http://code.google.com//apis/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/default.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&sensor=false"></script>
<script>
    var infowindow;
     function initialize() {
      infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow(); 
          var mapOptions = {
zoom: 2 ,
center: new google.maps.LatLng(-25.363882,131.044922),
mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
 };
       map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'),
         mapOptions);
         markerForWhatsHere = new google.maps.Marker({
          // position: position,
             map: map
        });
        google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function(e) {
          //   placeMarker(e.latLng, map);
         whatsHereEventLatLng=e.latLng;  
           whatsHere();
           });

                 }
        var markerForWhatsHere;
           var map ;
            function whatsHere(){
//alert("whats here latlng is "+ whatsHereEventLatLng);
if (markerForWhatsHere != undefined)   
{
 var addressForWhatsHere;
 var tmpName;
 markerForWhatsHere.setMap(null);
// google.maps.event.clearListeners(map, 'click');
 markerForWhatsHere.setPosition(null);
 markerForWhatsHere.setMap(map);
 markerForWhatsHere.setPosition(whatsHereEventLatLng);// updating marker positin for whats here
 var    image = "http://www.google.com/intl/en_ALL/mapfiles/marker_greenA.png";
 var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
 geocoder.geocode({
 latLng:whatsHereEventLatLng
                 }, function(responses,status) 
                 {
                    if (responses && responses.length > 0) 
                    {
                    addressForWhatsHere=responses[0].formatted_address;  //for address
                    //   alert("address is "+address);
                     for (i = 0; i < responses[0].address_components.length; ++i)//gettin city name where right click happen
                         {
                             for (j = 0; j < responses[0].address_components[i].types.length; ++j)
                             {
                             if (responses[0].address_components[i].types[j] == "locality") //for city
                                 {
                                  city = responses[0].address_components[i].long_name;  
                                 } 
                             }
                          } //end code for getting city
                    }
                    if(typeof(city)=='undefined')
                        city='Unknown';
                if(typeof(address)=='undefined')
                    address='Unknown';
                    infowindow.setContent("<b>Address : </b>"+addressForWhatsHere+" <br><b>City : </b>"+city+"<br><b> Lat.-lng. : </b>"+whatsHereEventLatLng);
                    infowindow.open(map, markerForWhatsHere);
                    markerForWhatsHere.setIcon(image);
                    var splitAddress=[];
                    splitAddress=address.split(",");
                    tmpName=splitAddress[0];
                    var markerTitle=image;


                });//end of geocoder


                google.maps.event.addListener(markerForWhatsHere, 'click', function (event) 
                        {
                    alert("addressForWhatsHere "+addressForWhatsHere);
                    if (event.alreadyCalled_) {
                       // alert('circle clicked again'); 
                    }
                    else {
                    var markerTitle=markerForWhatsHere.getIcon();
                        //  alert("marker title is "+markerTitle);

                            if(markerTitle.indexOf("green")!=-1)
                            {           //for marker selection
                                setMarkerTitle=markerTitle.replace("green","yellow");//changing color of marker
                                markerForWhatsHere.setIcon(setMarkerTitle);

                            }//end if marker is green                   //end of marker selection

                   if(markerTitle.indexOf("yellow")!=-1)
                            {//for marker unselection
                                                setMarkerTitle=markerTitle.replace("yellow","green");   //changing color of marker
         markerForWhatsHere.setIcon(setMarkerTitle);
          }//end if marker is yellow
                 event.alreadyCalled_ = true;        }
                     });//end of marker click           
}   
 infowindow.close();

             }

                google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);

              </script>
                 </head>
               <body>
                  <div id="map-canvas"></div>
                 </body>
               </html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Every time you click the map (after the first) you *move* the marker:

```
if (markerForWhatsHere != undefined)   
{
  // ...
 markerForWhatsHere.setPosition(whatsHereEventLatLng);
```

But add a new 'click' event listener to it:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(markerForWhatsHere, 'click', function (event) 
{
   alert("addressForWhatsHere "+addressForWhatsHere);
   if (event.alreadyCalled_) {
      // alert('circle clicked again'); 
   }
   else {
     var markerTitle=markerForWhatsHere.getIcon();
     if(markerTitle.indexOf("green")!=-1)
     { //for marker selection
       setMarkerTitle=markerTitle.replace("green","yellow");//changing color of marker
       markerForWhatsHere.setIcon(setMarkerTitle);
     }//end if marker is green                   //end of marker selection
     if(markerTitle.indexOf("yellow")!=-1)
     { //for marker unselection
       setMarkerTitle=markerTitle.replace("yellow","green");   //changing color of marker
       markerForWhatsHere.setIcon(setMarkerTitle);
     } //end if marker is yellow
     event.alreadyCalled_ = true;
  }
});//end of marker click
```

Only add the click listener if the marker was initially undefined or delete the marker and recreate it.

[working example](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_SO_multipleClickEventsA.html)

Comment: ya,i am moving my marker,your code is right but i want address on markers click not on map click,and according to you i am adding a new 'click' event listener,but i if clear my click listner before creating new then its not working again

Comment: and in your example alert is showing on map click, not on markers click,so this example not fulfill my req.

Comment: Got it,always  when we call whatshere method a new click event is added to the marker just add click listner to the initlize function and its working correctly.  Thanks @geocodeZip